# How to get this sequence list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I hope to get a list whose elements decrease by $2$ or increase by $1$, in turn, until the last element is $0$. For instance, starting with $4$ the sequence would be `{4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}`. If you gave me $5$ instead, the sequence would be `{5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}`.

This is my current method:

```
i = 1;
NestWhileList[If[++i; EvenQ[i], # - 2, # + 1]&, 5, UnequalTo[0]]
```

> {5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}

But I am not very satisfied with that intermediate variable `i`. I would like to find other methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f1 = FoldList[Plus, #, 3 Mod[Range[0, 2 (# - 2)], 2] - 2] &

f1 @ 5
```

> ```
> {5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}
> ```

```
f1 @ 4
```

> ```
> {4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}
> ```

Also

```
f2 = Accumulate @ Prepend[#] @ (3 Mod[Range[0, 2 (# - 2)], 2] - 2) &;

f2 @ 5
```

> ```
> {5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}
> ```

```
f2  @ 4
```

> ```
> {4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

A combination of `Range` and `Riffle` produces the desired result.

```
sequence[n_Integer] := Riffle[Range[n, 2, -1], Range[n - 2, 0, -1]]
```

Applying to 5

```
sequence[5]
(* {5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0} *)
```

Comment: The answer can solve this problem,I have thought it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137559/21532).But I don't like it still,because that two alternate function(`#-2&` and `#+1&`) can be more complicate function.Then this method will be run out.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

[Another](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/214956/106) use for [`SubstitutionSystem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubstitutionSystem.html), which I was unaware of before I read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/291542/106) great answer by @azerbajdzan.

```
SubstitutionSystem[{n_-> n-1}, {4,2},2]//Flatten

(* {4,2,3,1,2,0} *)
```

Or

```
SubstitutionSystem[{n_-> n+1}, {0,2},2]//Flatten//Reverse

(* {4,2,3,1,2,0} *)
```

```
(SubstitutionSystem[{n_->n+1}, {0,2},#]//Flatten//Reverse)&/@Range[2,10]

(* {
    {4,2,3,1,2,0},
    {5,3,4,2,3,1,2,0},
    {6,4,5,3,4,2,3,1,2,0},
    {7,5,6,4,5,3,4,2,3,1,2,0},
    {8,6,7,5,6,4,5,3,4,2,3,1,2,0},
    {9,7,8,6,7,5,6,4,5,3,4,2,3,1,2,0}, 
    {10,8,9,7,8,6,7,5,6,4,5,3,4,2,3,1,2,0}, 
    {11,9,10,8,9,7,8,6,7,5,6,4,5,3,4,2,3,1,2,0}, 
    {12,10,11,9,10,8,9,7,8,6,7,5,6,4,5,3,4,2,3,1,2,0}
   } *)
```

---

**Original Answer**

**(1)**

```
(NestList[#+1&,{0,2},2]//Flatten//Reverse)

(* {4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0} *)
```

**(2)**

```
(NestList[#+1&,{0,2},3]//Flatten//Reverse)

(*{5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0} *)
```

**(3)**

```
(NestList[#+1&,{0,2},#]//Flatten//Reverse)&/@Range[2,10]

(*
{
 {4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}, 
 {5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}, 
 {6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}, 
 {7, 5, 6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}, 
 {8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}, 
 {9, 7, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}, 
 {10, 8, 9, 7, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}, 
 {11, 9, 10, 8, 9, 7, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}, 
 {12, 10, 11, 9, 10, 8, 9, 7, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}
}
*)
```

**(4) Recursively**

```
If[#1[[-1]]>5, Nothing, #0[Sow[#1]+1]]&[{0,2}]//Reap//Flatten//Reverse

(* {5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0} *)
```

Comment: (+1) Simpler, nice!

Comment: Looking at the pattern in reverse!

Answer (score 3):

```
seq[n_ /; n > 1] := Reverse[Riffle[Range[0, n - 2], Range[2, n]]]
seq[6]
```

> {6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}

Answer (score 3):

```
seq[n_Integer?(GreaterThan[1])] := 
  Accumulate[Prepend[Most[ConstantArray[Splice[{-2, 1}], n - 1]], n]]
```

Or

```
seq[n_Integer?(GreaterThan[1])] := 
  Reverse@Most@FoldList[Plus, 0, ConstantArray[Splice[{2, -1}], n - 1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

A variant of one of the two forms proposed by @lericr:

```
seq[n_ /; n > 1] := 
 Reverse@FoldList[Plus, 0, Most@(Sequence @@@ ConstantArray[{2, -1}, n - 1])]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f[{x_, y_}] := {x + 1 - 3 Mod[y, 2], y + 1}
func[a_] := NestWhileList[f, {a, 1}, #[[1]] != 0 &][[All, 1]]
```

e.g.`func[10]` yields:

```
{10, 8, 9, 7, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
s[2] = {2, 0};
s[n_] := s[n] = {n, n - 2, Sequence @@ s[n - 1]}

s[6]
```

{6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0}

```
Information[s]
```