# Generating list with short code

Tags: manipulate, list-manipulation

I need to get this list

> {1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,7,6,8,7,9,8}

with a very small code (< 30 characters)
using Table and List functions.

On each step, either it

- subtracts 1
  or
- adds 2

I have tried

```
Range[1,18] + Table[(-i)*2^n, {i, -1, 1}, {n, 0, 1}
```

because I want $i = -1$ while $n = 0$ and $i = 1$ while $n = 1$, but I don't know how to set it up in one line.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: `Table[(n+3Mod[n,2])/2-1,{n,18}]`

Comment: Or `Table[Floor[n/2]-(-1)^n,{n,18}]`

Answer (score 13):

Well, without `Table` and such:

```
Riffle[Range[9], Range[0, 8]]
```

---

Or, we can use `SequenceFunction`:

```
FindSequenceFunction[Riffle[Range[9], Range[0, 8]]]
(* 1/4 (-1)^#1 (-3 + (-1)^(1 + #1) + 2 (-1)^#1 #1) & *)
```

So:

```
1/4 (-1)^#1 (-3 + (-1)^(1 + #1) + 2 (-1)^#1 #1) & /@ Range[18]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @march. I am just getting started and therefore very thankful for such nice moves.

Answer (score 8):

If you ***have to*** use `Table` you can get the desired result with 23 characters:

```
## &[i, i - 1]~Table~{i, 9}
```

> {1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8}

```
"##&[i,i-1]~Table~{i,9}" // StringLength
```

> 22

If not you can save a few key strokes using

```
## &[#, # - 1] &~Array~9
```

> {1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8}

```
"##&[#,#-1]&~Array~9" // StringLength
```

> 19

or using

```
## &[#, # - 1] & /@ Range @ 9
```

> {1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8}

```
"##&[#,#-1]&/@Range@9" // StringLength
```

> 20

Answer (score 7):

26 characters is the shortest I can think of:

```
{#, # - 1} & /@ Range@9 // Flatten
```

Comment: Using `Table` as requested, `Table[{n, n - 1}, {n, 9}] // Flatten` is still below 30.

Answer (score 7):

```
f[n_]:= Sequence[n, n - 1]
Array[f, 9]

(*{1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8}*)
```

or

```
Flatten@Array[{#, #-1}&, 9]

(*{1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8}*)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

From [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/291542/106) by @azerbajdzan, which introduced me to [`SubstitutionSystem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubstitutionSystem.html)

```
SubstitutionSystem[{n_ :> n+1}, {1,0}, 8]//Flatten

(* {1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,7,6,8,7,9,8} *)
```

---

**Original Answer**

```
Flatten@NestList[#+1&,{1,0},8]
```

> {1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8}

In addition

```
Array[{#,#-1}&,9,1,Join]
```

and

```
Array[{#+1,#}&, 9,0,Join]==Array[{#,#-1}&, 9,1,Join]
```

**Original Post**

```
NestList[#+{1,1}&, {1,0},8]//Flatten
```

Comment: Two more rather silly ones using `Sow`, `Reap` and (recursion with) `#0`: (i) `If[#1[[1]]>9, Nothing, #0[Sow[#1]+1]]&[{1,0}]//Reap//Flatten`  and (ii) `Nest[Sow[#]+1&, {1,0},9]//Reap//Rest//Flatten`

Answer (score 4):

> with a very small code (< 30 characters) using Table and List
>   functions.

If requirement to use Table only, then one way is

```
Flatten@Table[Table[i, {i, j, j - 1, -1}], {j, 1, 9}]
```

Gives

```
{1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or this (inspired by the FindSequenceFunction reported by @march):

```
ClearAll[aList, sf,testList];
aList = {1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8};
sf = FindSequenceFunction[aList];
testList = sf /@ Table[i, {i, 1, Length[aList]}]
aList == testList
(*{1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8}*)
(*True*)
```

Comment: `Table[i, {i, 1, Length[aList]}]` is equivalent (but potentially slower) than `Range[Length[aList]]`

Comment: Sure, but Table was requested in the OP.  I originally did it as Range and then changed it.